In angular 17 how to add facebook page-plugin
I have built an application in angular 17 and want to add a public facebook page in one of the component. I am able to load the facebook page in component however, it is not working properly.
Below is the code that i have implemented to add FB page in my app:

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/ generated the code to embed page in my website.

Added following script in index.html:
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v19.0&appId=36553205380XXXX" nonce="XXXXX"></script>


Added following html to include FB page in component:




<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook"
 data-tabs="timeline" data-width="" data-height="700" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true"
 data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/crossfit"
                                                               class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
                                                               




Added following code in component



      ngOnInit() {
        if(FB.XFBML != null) {
          FB.XFBML.parse()
        }
      }



FB page got loaded in component but i am getting errors like below  in console and it's not loading new posts when i am scrolling down. Instead it's repeating the posts from top.
Could not find element "u_1_50_IH" [Caught in: Module "__elem_6d29ee41_1_4_a2"] [Caught in: Module "__inst_6d29ee41_1_4_nL"] [Caught in: Module "__inst_a648e52c_1_8_OO"] [Caught in: Requiring module "__inst_a648e52c_1_8_OO" which threw an exception] [Caught in: Module "__inst_a176866d_1_4_XK"] [Caught in: Requiring module "__inst_a648e52c_1_8_OO" which threw an exception] [Caught in: Module "__inst_8c33f2cf_1_4_3G"] [Caught in: Requiring module "__inst_a648e52c_1_8_OO" which threw an exception] [Caught in: Module "__inst_492d06b7_1_4_oY"] [Caught in: Requiring module "__inst_a648e52c_1_8_OO" which threw an exception] [Caught in: Requiring module "__inst_a648e52c_1_8_OO" which threw an exception] [Caught in: Requiring module "__inst_a648e52c_1_8_OO" which threw an exception] [Caught in: Module "__inst_98d9a45e_1_8_OE"] [Caught in: Requiring module "__inst_a648e52c_1_8_OO" which threw an exception] [Caught in: Module "__inst_21a8c1d4_1_4_g+"] [Caught in: Requiring module "__inst_a648e52c_1_8_OO" which threw an exception] [Caught in: Module "__inst_866f970e_1_4_1G"] [Caught in: Requiring module "__inst_a648e52c_1_8_OO" which threw an exception] [Caught in: Module "__inst_c523de71_1_4_ef"] [Caught in: Requiring module "__inst_a648e52c_1_8_OO" which threw an exception] [Caught in: Module "__inst_1516ab8a_1_4_sJ"] [Caught in: Requiring module "__inst_a648e52c_1_8_OO" which threw an exception] [Caught in: Module "__inst_74f26af1_1_4_G9"] [Caught in: Requiring module "__inst_a648e52c_1_8_OO" which threw an exception] [Caught in: Module "__inst_9f6501f1_1_4_Xq"] [Caught in: Requiring module "__inst_a648e52c_1_8_OO" which threw an exception] [Caught in: Module "__inst_e698bc89_1_4_lH"] [Caught in: Requiring module "__inst_a648e52c_1_8_OO" which threw an exception] [Caught in: Module "__inst_70689822_1_4_p4"] [Caught in: Requiring module "__inst_a648e52c_1_8_OO" which threw an exception] [Caught in: Module "__inst_70dbca80_1_8_6O"] [Caught in: Requiring module "__inst_a648e52c_1_8_OO" which threw an exception] [Caught in: Module "__inst_57d19858_1_4_Rl"] [Caught in: Requiring module "__inst_6d29ee41_1_4_nL" which threw an exception]

- Also, when i am clicking on any post it opens FB in separate tab. It doesn't allow to add comment or like from website itself opposite to FB documentation "The Page plugin lets you easily embed and promote any public Facebook Page on your website. Just like on Facebook, your visitors can like and share the Page without leaving your site. "
Is it because FB script not loading in angular properly. I have event tried using some modules for FB but none was compatible with angular17. Any help would be appreciated.
